# Plot points on country map

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, plot

I have a dataset of data for a country, and I want to plot the data on the map of Norway. Would prefer black and white, and only Norway, and not other countries around. I have tried using GeoPandas with Shapefile with no success. I have just made a scatter plot of how I want it to look, but i want to add the country border around. Also if other have better ways to display the data, I am grateful for other solutions.

The goal is to show distribution of transactions and the color represents a certain value of the transaction, I also want to add legends for the color.

I have the coordinates in a pandas dataframe, and using Python with Jupyter Notebook.

[image: My solution so far]

Comment: The dupe explains how to add a background image to your plot. You need to find a suiteable map somewhere, f.e. here: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=map+black+and+white+norway&atb=v168-1&ia=images&iax=images

Comment: @PatrickArtner okey thanks, but will it put the coordinates on the right place on the image, I want the coordinates to match the point on the map. And I am also looking for other ways to solve it.

Comment: You need a map in scale to your data and need to supply it accordingly - guess you need some fiddling with it till it overlaps correctly. Probably need to take one map that suits you, make a pic of your dataplot and take it and the map into a gimp2 to rotate/scale the map to your liking. Then add it to your plot and adjust the parameters of it.